# How to write an array of strings into a single, formatted, string

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of items:

```
array(
    'apples',
    'oranges',
    'pineapples'
)
```

that I would like to format like so: "Some of my favorite fruits are `apples`, `oranges` and `pineapples`"

So, using `PHP` I would like to be able to transform that array into a reader friendly `apples, oranges and pineapples`.

At first I thought I might be able to use `array_map` but i'm not sure how I would go about telling what the last and 2nd to last items are (it's easy to add a `,` after each item with `array_map`, however you wouldn't want a comma before the last item)

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Divide the problem to conquer it: Take out the last element, create the comma separated list and then add the last element.

```
$array = array(
    'apples',
    'oranges',
    'pineapples'
);

$last = array_pop($array);
echo implode(', ', $array), ' and ', $last; # apples, oranges and pineapples
```

Naturally this only makes sense when there are at least two values in the array. Functions used: [`implode`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/implode) (probably more suitable than `array_map` in this case) and [`array_pop`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/array_pop).

---

On the other hand, if the values do not contain any `,` you can first create a comma separated string with the `implode` function and then use a regular expression to replace the last comma with `and`.

That done will also work on arrays that have less than 2 elements. I do this in a loop that removes one element from the array in each step so that it shows how it behaves:

```
$array = array(
    'apples',
    'oranges',
    'pineapples'
);

foreach($array as $v)
{
    echo preg_replace('(,([^,]*)$)', ' and$1', implode(', ', $array)), "\n";
    array_pop($array);
}
```

Output:

```
apples, oranges and pineapples
apples and oranges
apples
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so as others have commented `implode` is a solution.

I would probably end up using a combination of `implode`, `strripos` and `substr_replace`:

```
$string = implode(', ', $fruit); 
$pos = strripos($string, ', ');
echo substr_replace($string, ' and ', $pos, 2);
```

which results in `apples, oranges and pineapples`.

I'd gladly post a more elegant solution if I could think of one, but this is a quick and easy way to get at the change you need.

Comment: I concede that the one @hakre posted using "array_pop" is a cleaner way of doing it!

Answer (score 1):

You can know which one is the last element by counting them:

```
$array = array(
    'apples',
    'oranges',
    'pineapples'
);

$count= count($array);
// because the key start from 0 , we must subtract 1 
$lastKey= $count-1;


/// now u can do that
echo "<br>1st :".$array[0];
echo "<br>2nd :".$array[1];
echo "<br>3rd :".$array[2];
echo "<br>last:".$array[$lastKey];

// or same as u like

foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    echo $value;
    if($key == $lastKey){
        echo ".";
    }elseif($key == ($lastKey-1)){
        echo " and ";
    }else{
        echo " , ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your looking for [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php), which will essentially turn an array to string